# Can someone please explain COMTIMEOUTS for me?

Tags: windows, serial-port

I have an application that has strict timing.

Inter-character delay must be no more than is 0.15s

The messages themselves are quite small.  10 - 50 chars

I don't understand what ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier
and ReadTotalTimeoutConstant actually mean in practice.

The math in this example doesn't work?
http://www.lookrs232.com/com_port_programming/api_commtimeouts.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReadIntervalTimeout = max time between two bytes
ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = max time for a multi-byte read to complete
ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = extra time allowed for each byte in a multi-byte read

Since you specified a strict limit on the inter-character delay, you'll want to only set ReadIntervalTimeout.  Odd btw, the usual limit is a time-out on a message.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes it is odd, it's a very old protocol created back in the 1980's!